# conditionally switch history on temporal tables off

Tags: sql-server

we have a T-SQL migration script on SQL Server that we are testing. We need to delete certain data from temporal tables (but not all)  but randomly the script is failing right now. To delete the history we need to switch history off so no new history is generated and we can empty part of the history.

Due to the previous fails it leaves a table history off and doesnt switch it on at the end of the delete. The new run will fail switching the history off if it is already off.

1. How can i see which tables have their history currently switched off. SYS.TABLES doesnt show the current status or does it? Could not find it there.
2. Can i switch them on conditionally to make the script robust. A bit like a conditional IF EXISTS ...  DROP where a normal drop would fail if the object does not exist

Thanks!

Comment: Please show your existing script (or a simplified version of it)

Answer (score 1):

You can find out if a table has an associated history table via `sys.tables`

```sql
select
  t.name,
  t.history_table_id
from sys.tables t
where t.name in (
  'Table1',
  'Table2'
);
```

Tables with a `null` in `history_table_id` do not have a history enabled.

If you don't want to supply a list, you can check via `sys.columns` for a `PERIOD` column:

```sql
select
  t.name,
  t.history_table_id
from sys.tables t
where exists (select 1
    from sys.columns c
    where c.object_id = t.object_id
      and c.generated_always_type > 0
);
```

And the following script will automatically enable the history table using the default name.

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
select @sql =
  STRING_AGG('
ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + '
  SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON);
', '')
from sys.tables t
join sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = t.schema_id
where exists (select 1
    from sys.columns c
    where c.object_id = t.object_id
      and c.generated_always_type > 0
)
  and t.history_table_id is null;

PRINT @sql;  -- your friend

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/o-gkrOUb)